# Postgres not available as adapter on Induction

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, induction, postgres.app

I'm using Postgres.app and the latest build of Induction ( Version 0.1.0 (28) ) and I cannot choose "Postgres" as an adapter. I only have the options for mongodb, redis, and sqlite. If I attempt to type it in manually (i.e. "postgres://locahost"), it automatically reverts back to "(null)" instead, once I click another form input.

Is there somewhere I need to specify that I'm using Postgres locally (specifically with the PATH being set to the Postgres.app location in Applications)?

I'm using Mac OS X 10.8.2, Postgres 9.1.4, Postgres.app 1.0 (11), and Induction 0.1.0 (28).

Answer (score 0):

I have Induction working against PostgreSQL 9.3 as installed by Homebrew.

It sees that if you don't have a database set up then postgres does not appear in the adapter list, but when I came back to it after setting up PostgreSQL, creating a database and a user for it, then 'postgres' was available in the adapter.

Connecting it was as follows (one way, anyway)

Set the adapter as postgres, but instead of filling in the fields, click on the top field and enter the string:

postgres://user_name:user_pass@127.0.0.1/database_name

The 127.0.0.1 means you'll be connection over tcp/ip and will need (eg if running Rails) host: localhost in your database.yaml file under development